# LARAVEL - cannot access my public folder via URL

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I cannot acces my files in public folder via URL,while using artisan as server

For example:

### IN CHROME

http://localhost:8000/images/wolf.png give me *ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE*

### FIREFOX give me

[image]

### in IE it works fine

[image]

> I dont know if it has something to do with it but there is some kind
>   of block on icon. Then i added other images so those are not all.

[image]

My htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

### I tried set up new project but problem still persist.

Comment: what are you using as a server? and you got this error on `php artisan serve` ??

Comment: no, image is just not showing up, i am using php artisan serve or i cannot access my public folder at all, i mean in view

Comment: what response you will get on some other page like `localhost:8000/someotheroute`

Comment: and if route exist??

Comment: 404 page not found if route doesnt exist, if exist then it shows up.

Comment: ok, once try copy paste another image directly in some directory inside public, and try accessing that image directly via url `http://localhost:8000/somedir/imagename.jpg` if that works, then the problem is your current image or its permission. If not, then u need to restart your server or reconfigure it.

Comment: i copied different images in same folder but still same issue .....

http://localhost:8000/images/test.jpg  is ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE

and http://localhost:8000/public/images/test.jpg is 404 page

Comment: then try reconfiguring your server, this seems to be the issue of server. Try running this application from other server like apache or nginx instead of artisan.

Comment: You should not include the `public` folder in the url. Your public folder is the http root, so enteting `localhost:8000/somefile.php` is the same that acessing the `public/somefile.php`. Verify in your logs what the reason for the ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE

Comment: see edited question